# Need to Convert Binary to NVARCHAR IN SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert following Source (`Binary`) to Destination (`NVARCHAR(56)`). And don't know how it will be converted. I have tried `CONVERT` and it converts it to something like Chinese

```
Source:0x358C0F85A2DB47C9AC06FD392466EF0B
Destination:358C0F85A2DB47C9AC06FD392466EF0B
```

Comment: please provide some code and sample output and data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @varbinaryField VARBINARY(max);
SET @varbinaryField = 0x358C0F85A2DB47C9AC06FD392466EF0B

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), @varbinaryField, 2)
```